# How do I read data from two cells in a table row, perform calculations on the values then store the result into a third cell on the same row?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms, datatable

I'm still in the process of figuring out how to work with tables and data Grids so this is probably a dumb question showing lack of experience..but here goes. I have a table in which I want to multiply two values  and place the answer in a third cell on the same row in the table. The calculation(mainly multiplication)/method should produce a unique answer for each row in the table. I tried using a DataReader to pick values out from the table then perform the calculation and send the result back to the table but I couldn't figure out how to make the calculation take place uniquely for each row..Also Would it be wiser to create the column to place the answer before-hand or should I rather Update the table by adding a new column in the process? I hope someone gets me and can help me, thanks.

Comment: Why not perform this actions in your DataSource and just render the wanted value from the source ?

Comment: you can do this simply by executing an effective google search there are plenty of samples online.. have you even tried a google search at least..?

Comment: Create one more column in db,  do  auto calculate over there. Would be easy, fast and reliable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting the information from a database why not just do the calculation there. ColA * ColB as ColC

If you are doing different types of calculations that require that you be in C# code then you could create a column when the data is selected. Then when you create the data table you would need to set "ReadOnly" to false. Then you could say ColC = result

Comment: This is a comment.

Comment: Would that mean recreating the datatable if the format of the values are set to string?

Comment: If the values are stored in your DB as a string you can try and convert it in your sql query or in c# as stated above.

Comment: Thank you, let me try that and see how it turns out.. I appreciate it.